# AngularJs Url changes but old view is loaded using ui-router

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router and I have a setup like this

In app.js I have the following

```
 $stateProvider
      .state('TechReadiness', {
          url: "/Dashboard/TechReadiness",
          templateUrl: "/partials/TechnicalReadinessReport.aspx"
      })
    .state('TechReadiness.details', {
        url: "/ReadinessDetails/:a/:b",
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            return "/partials/TechReadinessDetails.aspx?b=" + $stateParams.b + '&a=' + $stateParams.a;
        }
    })
```

There is a page and on that page I am creating the links as shown below

```
$("#Chart5ImageMap area").each(function () {
                var vHref = $(this).attr('href');
                var arg1 = vHref.substring(vHref.indexOf("'") + 1, vHref.indexOf(",") - 1);
                var arg2 = vHref.substring(vHref.indexOf(",") + 2, vHref.lastIndexOf("'"));
                var a = arg2.split(',');
                $(this).attr('href', '#/Dashboard/TechReadiness/ReadinessDetails/' + a[0] +'/'+a[1]);
            });
```

This changes  all the click postback events(asp.net Chart Control) to simple links. Now the problem is that whenever I click the link the url gets updated correctly but the corresponding view doesn't get loaded.

for example: 
If I click the link with 
a=parameter1,b=parameter2

url becomes http://localhost:63893/#/Dashboard/TechReadiness/ReadinessDetails/parameter1/parameter2

accordingly and the correct view is loaded

but on when I click links with

a=parameter2,b=parameter2

the url changes to http://localhost:63893/#/Dashboard/TechReadiness/ReadinessDetails/parameter2/parameter2

but the content in the view doenst change

Comment: can u provide plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using ASP.Net and thus there was client side caching enabled on the pages because of the following line on top of pages

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" Location="Server" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

and I fixed it by replacing the above by

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" Location="Server" VaryByParam="a;b" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you already in the state "TechReadiness.details",  the view templateUrl will not **reload**. You should set the parametes to the controller but view template.